# How to access JSON object, 2 dimensional and single arrays at the same time in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

`PHP` file returns `json_encode` data and possible to view on `jquery` as follows. Now i want to display `PHP` if condition else part (When no record found from the table) on `jquery.` How to do it?

`PHP` function

```
if($query->num_rows()){
    echo(json_encode($query->result()));
    //returns
    //[{"id":"24","content":"maths","email":"samplestudent@gmail.com"}]
} 
else {            
    $response["error"] = 1;
    $response["error_msg"] = "NO records found";
    echo json_encode($response);
    //returns  
    //{"error":1,"error_msg":"NO records found"}
}
```

Jquery

```js
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxUrl,
  dataType: "JSON",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(retdata) {        
      $.each(retdata, function(i) {
         $("#main_div").append(retdata[i].email + '<br>');
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Wrap them in object and echo only once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check whether a object contains some key or not.

```
success: function(retdata) { 
      if(retdata.hasOwnProperty("error")){
         alert(retdata.error_msg);
         return;
      }      

      // else treat it like a normal array
      $.each(retdata, function(i) {
         $("#main_div").append(retdata[i].email + '<br>');
      });
  }
```

And a array in Javascript is nothing but a Object whose key is ordered integers starting from 0. So it won't throw any error if the argument is array or object.

Comment: good explanation and working solution..can you please enplane `hasOwnProperty` has parameter 'error' Is that my 1st array value?

Comment: Yes that is your first associative array index.

Comment: @GeethWelagedara you can check your PHP response. JS side code looks good to me

Answer (score 1):

can be simply check by `typeof` condition

```
success: function(retdata) { 
      if(typeof retdata.error == "undefined"){ //check error value is undefined [not exist]            
         $.each(retdata, function(i) {
         $("#main_div").append(retdata[i].email + '<br>');
         });
      }          
      else{
        alert(retdata.error_msg);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
if($query->num_rows()){
    echo(json_encode($query->result()));
}else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 204 No Content");          
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "POST",
    statusCode: {
        200: function() {
            // Code when records are found
        },
        201: function() {
            // Code when records are not found
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if retdata result received by jquery is a table. (Use `isArray` jquery function) http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/
If is, do loop for each record, if not display the `error_msg`